# Ordering more units than stocking

Tags: probability

This is page 142 of Sheldon Ross' "A First Course in Probability, edition 10". The question is given below:

> A product that is sold seasonally yields a net profit of b dollars for each unit sold and
> a net loss of $l$ dollars for each unit left unsold when the season ends. The number
> of units of the product that are ordered at a specific department store during any
> season is a random variable having probability mass function p(i), $i \geq 0$. If the store
> must stock this product in advance, determine the number of units the store should
> stock so as to maximize its expected profit.

My idea was: let $x$ be the number of units stocked, and $t$ be the number of units sold. Then, we have the profit $P$ as

$$
P = tb - (x - t)l
$$

The answer (see below) however considers a different case where $x < t$, but how can be possible (i.e, how can we sell more units than we ordered)? I am not sure what I could be missing - is this due to the random variable?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not following.  Note that the official solution is using a different $X$ than you are.  In that solution, $X$ is the number of units *ordered*, and $s$ is the number of units *stocked*.

Comment: @lulu I'm not entirely sure on the distinction between ordered and stocked products in their solution, given that the question references products being stocked (which I denote as $x$) and sold (which I denote as $t$). Could be misreading the question though.

Comment: The market "orders" a number of units, which the official solution denotes as $X$.  That's the only random variable in the problem.  Now, the store owner has stocked some number of units, $s$.  A priori, there need be no particular relation between $X$ and $s$ (though the store owner would prefer that they be as close as possible).  If $X>s$ then all $s$ units are sold, but there is unmet demand.  If $X≤s$ then demand is satisfied, but the store owner may be left with unsold inventory.  Of course $X=s$ is the storeowner's best outcome, but it usually isn't something they can guarantee.

Comment: The usual meaning of "Stockings" is not this one :)

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion arises from the wording that is used in the question and in the provided answer.  When Ross uses the term "ordered," he is not referring to the store's perspective, but rather, the customers'; that is to say, "ordered" as he uses it is synonymous with "purchased/sold."  He only ever uses the word "stock" to refer to how much inventory the store decides to hold in advance.

With this understanding, the only random variable here is the number of units that are "ordered" (i.e., purchased from the store), which is not known in advance.  The number of units stocked by the store is not a random variable.  It is a fixed and known quantity that is entirely within the store's control to decide.  This distinction is further implied by the use of an upper case $X$ for the former, and a lower case $s$ for the latter.

Then, as is shown in the solution, if $X$ is the random number of units sold, the profit $P(s)$ as a function of the number of units stocked $s$, is
$$P(s) = \begin{cases} bX - (s-X)\ell, & X \le s \\ bs, & X > s, \end{cases}$$ because in the first case where the demand $X$ does not exceed the supply $s$, the store realizes $bs$ in profit for the $X$ units sold, but $(s-X)\ell$ in losses for the $s-X$ units left unsold.  However, when the demand exceeds the supply, the store sells out:  there are no losses on excess inventory, and the store realizes $bs$ in profit.

Note that $P(s)$ is not a mass function.  I find Ross' choice of notation, like his wording, unfortunate; instead, I would have written it as $R(X; s)$ or $R(X \mid s)$.  I would use $R$ for "returns" so as to avoid confusing it with a probability function which is often denoted with $P$ or $\Pr$, and to take into account that depending on the choices of $b$, $s$, and $\ell$, it is actually possible for the store to realize a negative return (whereas "profit" usually implies a positive return).  My notation also emphasizes that the return is in essence a *transformation* of the underlying random variable $X$--i.e., $R$ is itself a random variable whose realizations are tied to realizations of $X$, and that $s$ is akin to a parameter.

In any case, the rest of the solution follows as shown by Ross.  Ultimately, I think this problem is a good illustration of the importance of clarity in language as well as in use of notation; the actual mathematics is not particularly complex.

Comment: @lulu I got the two variables confused when I wrote the answer--it has since been fixed.